# I am made feel tired by hot weather

Tags: passive-voice

> Hot weather makes me feel tired.

What is the passive voice of the above sentence?

> I am made feel tired by hot weather.

Is it correct?

Should we use "the" with "hot weather"?

Comment: "I am made *to feel tired* by hot weather", but someone else will have to explain the exact grammar of this.

Comment: Hot weather makes me tired. Hot weather is tiring for me.

Comment: @WillowRex - Ah, but neither of those is actually passive.

Comment: @stangdon -- which is why I did not dare answer. I don't understand what passive means. If you explain it, maybe I'll get it!

Comment: We find ourselves tiring when doing something that is tiring. Adjective **tired** already contains the idea that something has tired us. It is already a passive.  We are put into the state **tired** by the difficulty of the task (or the oppressive heat)

Comment: @TRomano Shouldn't passive voice has "to be" verb followed by past participle?

Comment: *I am tired by the heat.*  The heat tires me.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=JZMDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA100&dq=%22tired+by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY2ZWRhLvSAhUnwYMKHb3jCOEQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22tired%20by%22&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Make* is an exceptional verb.  It takes bare infinitival complements in the active:

> Hot weather makes me **feel tired**.

But *to*-infinitival complements in the passive:

> I am made **to feel tired** by hot weather.

This isn't a great example, though, because this passive is likely to be infelicitous (inappropriate).  Most of the time, people would favor the active version of this sentence; there is unlikely to be a specific reason to use the passive version.

We can come up with more natural-sounding examples:

> My parents made me **wash the dishes**.  (active)
>   I was made **to wash the dishes**.  (passive)

In this case, most people would favor the active version, but the passive version works if (for example) the speaker wishes to avoid saying who made them wash the dishes, so the passive is a bit more natural here.

Answer (score 2):

"Make" can be used in different patterns.
In your sentence you should use 
**Make+object +adjective complement**

> Hot weather makes me tired.I am made tired by hot weather. (I am tired of hot weather.

In the active voice, *make* meaning "force someone to do something " is used with an infinitive without *to*. In the passive voice *to* should be used:

> My boss made me work an extra day. I was made **to** work an extra day.
>   Hot weather makes me feel tired. I am made to feel tired by hot weather.